# Your app isn't using AndroidX - Flutter doesn't allow me to generate apk

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, dart

I developed an app in flutter with Visual Studio code on Mac. I ran the application without any kind of problem on IOS. I also installed it on a physical device and it works perfectly, but I have a problem generating the Android project study and its APK on with flutter.

**Message**:

```
flutter build appbundle
[!] Your app isn't using AndroidX.
    To avoid potential build failures, you can quickly migrate your app by following the
    steps on ...
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                                  
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.      
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                                                     Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.              
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                                                                                                        
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... Done                       217,9s (!)
Gradle build failed to produce an .aab file. It's likely that this file was generated under
/Users/riccardo/Desktop/QuoteFlutter/quote/build, but the tool couldn't find it.
```

Comment: Have you attempted to follow the instructions given yo you and updating your app to use AndroidX?

Comment: pls try this, for more log info,   flutter build apk -v, may be problem in android x migration

Comment: Try using flutter clean command and then build apk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this because your project is missing gradle.prperties file >> open terminal in android studio or vs code and write "flutter create ." it will create missing file one of them is gradle.properties.

Answer (score 11):

in my own case my gradle.properties was missing. I Just created a new gradle.properties file  inside the android folder, with the below parameter

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.enableR8=true
```

Answer (score 4):

you should go to

YourAppName=> android => gradle.properties

inside gradle.properties add these two lines

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

dat should solve it.

Answer (score 3):

The error description clearly states that

> Your app isn't using AndroidX.
>       To avoid potential build failures, you can quickly migrate your app by following the
>       steps on ...

### How to resolve this?

Follow [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration) detailed documentation.

Answer (score 3):

its **August 2021**

**Answer:**
if you are not using `android studio` as i am using `vscode`.

add below lines to ***flutter_app_path/android/gradle.properties.***

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Google introduced android jetpack(another topic) in which `AndroidX` package name and namespace default for jetpack libraries and minimum `support library 28` required what i guess now flutter team wants to migrate `flutter` support to `android jetpack` near future. come to  point now  migrating to `androidx` make sure your project has `support library 28`

add below lines to ***flutter_app_path/android/app/build.gradle***.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
// other lines of code
}
```

**Optional Story**
i had same issue when i cloned my old [flutter repo](https://github.com/iammohsinar/flutterfacebookcloneprofile.git)
if you have cloned `flutter legacy app` repo from github and your development flutter SDK version is `2.2.x` first you need to migrate your app to [NULL Safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide) after you should migrate to `androidx` follow my **Answer**

Answer (score 2):

I had an old project using Firestore, that I was trying to open, and got this message. I could not find any easy way to fix it.

These were the steps I took to migrate it, hope it helps someone.

Create a new folder.

Then run this command in Terminal, in the folder:

```
flutter create --org com.yourdomain your_app_name
```

Copy the files from lib folder, (and any other modifications from android or ios folders).

Copy google-services.json to android\app folder.

Modify pubspec.yaml and copy the dependencies under dependencies:

Change android\app\build.gradle change version to:

```
minSdkVersion 21
```

Add the plugins needed in android\app\build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In Android\build.gradle file:
Add the dependency (with your version):

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your project to AndroidX. Execute the following command:

```
flutter create --androidx -t <project-type> <new-project-path>
```

Project types can be **app**, **package** or **plugin**

More information [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47818#issuecomment-569218656).

Note: This Problem can also come while building an app downloaded from github, in VSCode with Flutter.

Answer (score -2):

if you want an APK then use

```
flutter clean
flutter build apk
```